# QGIS auto backup... is there one I can set?

Tags: qgis, data-backup

I see QGIS makes a backup of the last manually saved project.  But how about a timed interval that automatically makes backups as I work.  Just had a QGIS crash dump, lost lot's of work.  Can't save after every item I edit.

If there is not one I am surprised this has not been requested as a feature in the past.

Answer (score 12):

Probably what you want is an autosave function.

There is an autoSaver plugin that you can install, that provides a basic autosave function for the current project and modified layers in edit mode, running at a specified interval. You can also specify to autosave into an alternate backup file.

You can find the plugin in the QGIS Python plugin repository: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/autoSaver/.

Comment: As chkaiser said this plugin is great. It saves a *.bak version of your project in the projects original folder location. Upon a crash simply navigate tot he folder, remove ".bak" from the name and open with QGIS. This plugin already saved me a load of work